# cant do port forwarding ro my webrick server to access it from the net!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, portforwarding, webrick

i am developing a facebook app and i am using for that facebooker plugin and webrick server.
i have configured correctly my router to froward ports to my machine for 2 ports (80 and 3000)
the apache server can be accessed from the net http://ip:80 amd the webrick server can     http://ip:3000 , 
i dont understand why , please help me.

Answer (score 2):

What IP address do you have WEBrick set to listen on? My guess is it could be set to “127.0.0.1” which would cause the problem you’re describing. If so, set it to “0.0.0.0” and see if that works. If you’re starting the server with `script/server`, you can specify the IP to bind to with the `-b` flag:

```
script/server webrick -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it from another Network not in your network. Because your server is running on IP and your accessing machine is also connected to the same IP[because of port forwarding]. So it will not work in same network. You have to access it from different WAN IP Network.

Comment: I think this answer shouldn't be devalued because there are some routers which doesn't support reverse NAT. In those cases the <externalip>:<externalport> won't work. The site should be accessed from outside. This was in my case 'HUAWEI' model 'HG655b'...
In my case I have a secondary backup internet and I am using that to access the port forwarded server.