# Access WEBrick server from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I want to be able to access my development server from a machine outside of my home.
I have tried to run `rvmsudo rails server -p 80`, but when I try to access my computer with my IP, I get to the configuration page of my router...

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220621/setting-up-the-webrick-to-serve-to-internet-my-rails-app

Comment: For those who find this now: this was my issue: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325663/access-webrick-rails-from-another-computer-on-local-network/28948293#28948293)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up port forwarding on your router? What is the make and model of your router?

See there answers for more help:

- [Setting up the Webrick to serve to internet my rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220621/setting-up-the-webrick-to-serve-to-internet-my-rails-app)
- [cant do port forwarding ro my webrick server to access it from the net!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497869/cant-do-port-forwarding-ro-my-webrick-server-to-access-it-from-the-net)

Comment: Problem was that I was testing the external IP from within my home network. From outside it works well.

Comment: Will a proxy work? I'm inside my network and have no way to try to connect from outside it so I've been using web proxies to fake connecting from outside.

If the answer is yes then I have a problem because my address is reserved, my port is forwarded and my rails server is using binding 0.0.0.0 and I still can't connect using my WAN IP over a proxy.

Answer (score 8):

Testing here, to me works like this:

**-d** = daemon service

**-b 0.0.0.0** = make outside access enabled

So, the command is:

```
$ rails s -d -p 80 -b 0.0.0.0
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are already having a service (like apache web server) listening on port 80.

All you have to do, is pick a port that's unoccupied and bind the service to it.

```
rails s -d -p PORT_NUMBER
```

Then you must set up port-forwarding for that port.

Last but not least, if you have a dynamic (it changes over time) IP address (most common), you must always know your current IP. (http://whatismyip.com)

Then you can connect to your web app like this

```
http://CURRENT_IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER
```