# Main Rails app cannot connect to secondary app when using USB-connected mobile Safari client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, mobile, safari

Got a main app running on port 3002 and a second one running on port 3000. When using the main app from a browser (tested Chrome, Firefox, Safari), everything works just fine, including mounting the second app in an iframe.

The problem I'm having is when I jump to debug the mobile version on my iPhone's Safari, the main app is failing to load the support app with error message 'Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.'

Both apps are Rails applications, with the secondary app running on a WEBrick HTTP Server. On the secondary app I added the following lines in application.rb to for CORS support, with no success:

```
    config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
    })
```

Another piece of the puzzle: when I switch the secondary app URL to the production one deployed in Heroku, the main app successfully loads it in the iFrame. So--issue is only happening when the secondary app is running locally.

Appreciate any pointers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned about this not too long ago. It explains the why but does not offer a fix.

'You have to access it from another Network not in your network. Because your server is running on IP and your accessing machine is also connected to the same IP[because of port forwarding]. So it will not work in same network. You have to access it from different WAN IP Network.'

[cant do port forwarding ro my webrick server to access it from the net!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497869/cant-do-port-forwarding-ro-my-webrick-server-to-access-it-from-the-net)